# 421 4.3.0 Temporary System Problem. Try again later (10)

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, gmail, nodemailer

I am using nodemailer npm package with gmail as a service in nodejs.
For some of the emails I am getting below error,

```
 Data command failed: 421 4.3.0 Temporary System Problem.  Try again later (10). c124sm10820896qke.13 - gsmtp
at SMTPConnection._formatError (/home/ubuntu/node_12-24/Roo-Node/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:606:19)
at SMTPConnection._actionDATA (/home/ubuntu/node_12-24/Roo-Node/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:1449:34)
at SMTPConnection._responseActions.push.str (/home/ubuntu/node_12-24/Roo-Node/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:1421:26)
at SMTPConnection._processResponse (/home/ubuntu/node_12-24/Roo-Node/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:762:20)
at SMTPConnection._onData (/home/ubuntu/node_12-24/Roo-Node/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:558:14)
at TLSSocket._socket.on.chunk (/home/ubuntu/node_12-24/Roo-Node/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:510:47)
at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:211:7)
at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:250:11)
at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:208:10)
at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:597:20)
```

I saw multiple things about this but not a perfect solution